# kendo chart dynamic series

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, series

I currently have a two step process for my kendo charts.  The first process is allowing the user to select the datasets (series) they want on the chart.  They then choose a template.  A template is the graph settings ex (color theme, chart type line, bar, circle ect.).

Currently if a user selects the datasets they want i return the series information to the graph and the graph is then populated with the template settings.

I also allow the user to change the template settings on the fly. For example a Bar chart to Line, Area, Circle ect.  They can also change the theme.  The issue becomes when the first load is set, the series information that i pass is:

```
{
  [name: "string", data: []], 
  [name: "string", data: []]
}
```

when i inspect the series object after the change on the template I see the following added to the object:

```
{
  [name: "string",
   data: [],
   type: "area",
   color: "ff6800",
   ect...   
  ],
  [name: "string",
   data: [],
   type: "area",
   color: "ff6800",
   ect...   
  ],
}
```

The issue becomes that I can modify my object type to the correct selected type.  I can even change the color value to a differen color for each series.  However, because I am using the Kendo Themes, the chart background will change but then the series colors wont match.  I could come up with a function to choose the background color for the chart and then choose what colors you want for your series. But I would rather use the kendo methods if possible.

I also think if i clear out that object and just use the settings and data I am passing it could work.  However, I dont want to have to go to the database each time a page level changes is made and I also noticed that my object even if i create a temp object is given all of the chart properties.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question on Kendo forums and recieved the following answer.

You'll need to keep a deep copy of the chart options before passing them in. This way you can recreate the chart with only your original options.

```
var options = { ... };

$("#chart").kendoChart(
     // No side effects on options
     $.extend(true, {}, options)
 );
```

If you look at the example this makes sense to do it this way because then you can modify your chart when different events on the page occur.  For example when I want to change a theme or a chart type.  I can just modify the:

```
options.seriesDefaults = { type = "bar" };
```

Here is a link to an example provided by Tsvetomir: http://jsbin.com/ulohof/1/edit

Here is a link to the question on Kendo Forums: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/kendo-chart-dynamic-series.aspx